# Interpreting OLS regression coefficients of set of dummies when dependent var is in ln form

Tags: regression, least-squares, regression-coefficients, logarithm

I run a regression where I created a set of dummies to represent different intervals. I had set of 4 dummies, only included 3 in the regression so the one with the highest interval (experience) acts as a benchmark. 
How do I interpret those if my dependent variable is in ln form? I have no clue how to interpret this also in relation to the benchmark variable when I have multiple sets of dummy variables.

For example, if the benchmark is 'bigger AS size' and the AS 5000m is negative -,764 does that mean that having only 'AS 5000m' decreases the output but by
how much? 76,4% ? or only 0,764? I am not sure how to interpret the constant since it is in log and it also represents the benchmark for other dummies in the regression...

I have shortened the model, but there are in essence two 'sets' of dummies (locations and the size intervals) and two normal dummies.

```
variable              B coeff. 
(Constant)           6,281
Car                  ,389
Inclination (dummy)  -,125
Fallow Land (dummy)  -,072
ln Input (USD/ha)    ,180
No_Agroforestry      -,210
**AS_5000m2          -,764**
ln Land (ha)         -,337
P2: Sacaba          -,042
P3:Tiquipaya       -,130
P7:Tapacari       -,846
```

Comment: I think you will find the information you need in the linked threads. Please 
read them. If they aren't what you want / you still have a question afterwards, 
come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still 
need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just 
duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tips but sadly it did not help at all. My problem is in combining those two problems. I understand how to interpret data when only one dummy/log var is present in the model but I have multiple dummies and it is in log form...

Comment: I added a couple more duplicates for your consideration.  If that's not enough, [searching our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=log+regression+categorical+interpret+-logistic+-interaction) exposes a few dozen more to examine.

Comment: Can you clarify what you understand thus far, & what you still don't get? I don't see what else there is to say beyond what is already in the linked threads. If you understand how to interpret dummies & how to interpret results when y* is ln(y), you have everything. If you don't, that information is in the linked threads.